# Reprex error on Linux: No input provided and clipboard is not available

Tags: r, linux, reprex

Unable to generate reprex on Linux. When I try a simple example

```
  (y <- 1:4)
  mean(y)
```

I get the following message

```
No input provided and clipboard is not available.
Rendering reprex...
Clipboard on X11 requires 'xclip' (recommended) or 'xsel'.
Unable to put result on the clipboard. How to get it:
* Capture what `reprex()` returns.
* Consult the output file. Control via `outfile` argument.
Path to `outfile`:
    * /tmp/RtmpRYA93G/reprex16f2e48b49ed7/reprex_reprex.md
Open the output file for manual copy?
1: yes
2: no
```

and the following output in my viewer

```
 No user-supplied code found … so we’ve made some up. You’re welcome!

 sprintf("Happy %s!", weekdays(Sys.Date()))
 #> [1] "Happy Friday!"
 Created on 2020-10-16 by the reprex package (v0.3.0.9001)
```

Is it a clipboard issue on Linux?
Thanks for helping out.

Comment: From [the docs](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) it does recommend having `xclip` or `xsel`  installed on linux to access the clipboard. Have you installed those? Did you copy the code do your clipboard before running `reprex()` (that's where it assumed the input comes from). You can also not use your clipboard. For example `reprex::reprex({(y <- 1:4); mean(y)})`

Comment: `reprex::reprex({(y <- 1:4); mean(y)})` works. 
At this stage, I don't have the sudo access to install `xclip` or `xsel`, but will try it out again when I get those packs installed. Thank you MrFlick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clipboard is not generally available on Linux and users have to install `xclip` if they want to run `reprex`. An alternative is to not use the clipboard as suggested in MrFlick's comment

```
reprex::reprex({(y <- 1:4); mean(y)})
```